# CodeIgniter database query into table class

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

I am currently developing a module for ExpressionEngine and have a quick questions regarding outputting database queries into the table class.

The only way I have managed to do this is via the following:

```
$this->EE=& get_instance();
$this->EE->load->library('table');

    $data = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM my_table");

    echo $this->EE->table->generate($data);
```

This is great, but I would like to input some additional options in the table such as "Duplicate" and "Delete". To do this I need to be able to out put the query results individually. I have attempted the following:

```
$this->EE=& get_instance();
$this->EE->load->library('table');

$query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM my_table");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
  {
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $this->EE->table->add_row(
                echo $row['id']."<br />\n";
            );
        }
  }


echo $this->EE->table->generate();
```

With the above I receive the following error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting '".

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Many thanks
Ben

Comment: You cannot echo inside a function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $this->EE->table->add_row($row['id']);
```

Try that instead.

Comment: thanks for the response!! That works, but I now need to add additional  items in each row. For example each row with have 4 columns, id, key, duplicate link, delete link. Many thanks

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html will show you the proper format for adding rows. Basically a comma seperated list of cells, the above will create a single cell row for example. The examples provided in the link will make 3 cell rows.

Comment: scrap that i got it. Thanks again :)